# Pushed commit doesn't appear on Github

Tags: magit

I tried updating a repository about 30 minutes ago with only 3 lines being different and it has yet to show up as a commit on Github. Is it typically this slow? It shows that it went through and everything is up to date on Magit but not on Github. I have just the basic from Melpa and looked at this link [Magit commit is slow even for tiny changes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40518/magit-commit-is-slow-even-for-tiny-changes) but it isn't quite what I'm looking for. So any help is greatly appreciated.

BTW I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Emacs 25.2.2 and the most recent version of Magit, just installed it an hour ago.

Edit: It has been about an hour and it still hasn't gone through to Github.

Comment: No, that's not normal.  Your question is lacking information.  "it has yet to show up as a commit" ... "It shows that it went through and everything is up to date" -- Which is it?  How are you ascertaining things?  What does the Magit process buffer (type `$`) say about it?  Is it different if you do it from the command line?

Comment: Okay, I see the confusion caused there. That's because I went back to edit the post and didn't reread, I'll fix that. What I mean is that on Github the commit hasn't shown up yet but in Magit it tells me that it is finished. Though it looks like it just now went through. Also, thanks for the response, I appreciate it.

Comment: How long would it typically take?

Comment: Actually pushing the changes shouldn't be any slower than from the command line.  Reported "slowness" in Magit is invariably to do with it updating its UI / status buffer -- when there are a lot of changes for it to display, it has to do a lot of elisp work, and often has to call a lot of git commands (which on Windows is very slow, so that compounds matters).  Magit often needs to perform those updates after an action, but the actual push is just telling git to push -- exactly as you'd do from the command line; so if Magit is responsive and didn't report any errors, then it's done.

Comment: i.e. I can't explain what caused the delay, but I wouldn't *expect* it to be anything to do with Magit.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Github [was having issues yesterday](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/8x69vj1xyp9v).

Magit (i.e. `git push ...`) succeeded and if you had cloned the repository again (e.g. using `git clone ....`), then you most likely would have gotten the new commit. But the representation of the repository webpage at https://github.com/owner/name was not updated immediately due the difficulties that Github was having.

As explained in the comments above the push was not "slow"; it succeeded quickly, probably in a second or so.